# How to get index(of:) to return multiple indices?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift4

Here is a group array.

```
var group = ["H","H","E","D",
             "G","D","G","E",
             "D","B","A","B",
             "A","A","G","C",
             "C","H","D","G",
             "H","B","E","F",
             "F","C","E","A",
             "B","C","F","F"]
```

I want to do something like this to find indices of "A".

```
group.index(of: "A"!)
```

But this will return only first index, but not other indices for next three "A"s.

```
print(group.index(of: "A")!) //10
```

What do I do to get the program to return all four indices for "A"?

Comment: make a cycle and add your index in an array of int

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might use a combination of `enumerated` and `compactMap`:

```
let indexArray = group.enumerated().compactMap {
   $0.element == "A" ? $0.offset : nil
}    
print(indexArray) // [10, 12, 13, 27]
```

Comment: Note: This will be called `compactMap` soon

Comment: The type annotation on `indexArray` is not needed.

Answer (score 8):

Or just enumerate/filter/map :

```
 group.enumerated().filter{$1=="A"}.map{$0.offset}
```

[EDIT] Changed $0.0 to $0.offset as per Alexander's recommendation (makes the code more legible/explicit)

Comment: I would recommend `$0.offset` over `$0.0`

Comment: @Alexander Why, out of curiosity?

Comment: @creeperspeak Because it's not immediately obvious whether `.0` is `.element` or `.offset`. Making readers have to look up documentation to save 5 characters is silly. Code is read a lot more often than it's written.

Comment: @creeperspeak It can get pretty extreme if abused: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153716/11490

Comment: @Alexander Yep, I agree.  I thought maybe you had some non-style reason, which is why I asked.  Thanks!

Comment: swift 5.2 or later you can use keyPath `map(\.offset)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple cycle

**Use this Code**

```
var group = ["H","H","E","D",
             "G","D","G","E",
             "D","B","A","B",
             "A","A","G","C",
             "C","H","D","G",
             "H","B","E","F",
             "F","C","E","A",
             "B","C","F","F"]
var indexes : [Int] = []
for (index,string) in group.enumerated() {
    if(string == "A") {
        indexes.append(index)
    }
}

debugPrint(indexes)
```

Comment: Works, but the manual enumeration/appending is not as nice as the function approach. You forgot to `reserveCapacity`, too

Comment: @Alexander what you mean with `reserveCapacity`?

Comment: Actually nevermind, I thought this was a `map` operation (which has a known result array size), but it's actually a `filter` (which doesn't), so that part of my comment doesn't apply

Comment: I don't know the number of values that I need to add, that is why I ask, ok @Alexander thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness this is another different approach which `filter`s the `indices`

```
let group = ["H","H","E","D",
             "G","D","G","E",
             "D","B","A","B",
             "A","A","G","C",
             "C","H","D","G",
             "H","B","E","F",
             "F","C","E","A",
             "B","C","F","F"]

let indices = group.indices.filter{ group[$0] == "A"}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `reduce`, generic, based solution:

```
let group = ["H","H","E","D",
             "G","D","G","E",
             "D","B","A","B",
             "A","A","G","C",
             "C","H","D","G",
             "H","B","E","F",
             "F","C","E","A",
             "B","C","F","F"]

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func indexes(of element: Element) -> [Index] {
        return enumerated().reduce([]) { $1.element == element ? $0 + [$1.offset] : $0 }
    }
}

group.indexes(of: "A") // 10, 12, 13, 27]
```

Another approach would be to built-up a letter-to-indices dictionary and query that:

```
let indices = Dictionary(group.enumerated().map { ($1, [$0]) }, uniquingKeysWith: +)
indices["A"] ?? [] // [10, 12, 13, 27]
```

, though for this solution you'd need to unwrap the result as the dictionary subscript returns an optional value.

BTW, your array could've been a `let` instead of a `var`, constants bring predictability over your code, I recommend using them as much as possible.

Comment: You can use Swift 4 reduce into and no need to create a new array of a single element to append it to the partial result `reduce(into: []){ $1.element == "A" ? $0.append($1.offset) : () }`

Comment: kkkk You prefer to implement yourself instead of using the method created exactly for it

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the `Motivation` Swift evolution post https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0171-reduce-with-inout.md

Comment: `Dictionary(group.enumerated().map { ($1, [$0]) }, uniquingKeysWith: +)`

Comment: You forgot the `.map { ($1, [$0]) }`

Answer (score 1):

Vadian's answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022882/2857130) is already the most concise yet.

The rest of the answers just dance about chained HUFs because it's cool but just for true completeness, as the most basic implementation one would obviously do the following:

```
let group = ["H","H","E","D",
             "G","D","G","E",
             "D","B","A","B",
             "A","A","G","C",
             "C","H","D","G",
             "H","B","E","F",
             "F","C","E","A",
             "B","C","F","F"]

var array = [Int]()
for index in 0..<group.count {
    if group[index] == "A" {
        array.append(index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading about `Extensions` and functional programming past few days, I wanted to try writing an extension function for `Array` class. Here it is:

```
var group = ["H","H","E","D",
             "G","D","G","E",
             "D","B","A","B",
             "A","A","G","C",
             "C","H","D","G",
             "H","B","E","F",
             "F","C","E","A",
             "B","C","F","F"]

var group2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

// Create a nice Array extension method that will return indices of wanted group.

extension Array where Element: Equatable {

func showIndices(indexOf groupName: Element) -> [Int] {
    return self.enumerated().compactMap {
        $0.element == groupName ? $0.offset : nil
    }
}
}

group.showIndices(indexOf: "A")
group2.showIndices(indexOf: 1)

// [10, 12, 13, 27]
// [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend collection and create your own indices method that takes a predicate.

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    func indices(where predicate: @escaping (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Index] {
        try self.indices.filter({try predicate(self[$0])})
    }
    func indices(of element: Element) -> [Index] {
        self.indices.filter({self[$0] == element})
    }
}
```

For collections indexed by Int you can return an IndexSet:

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable, Index == Int {
    func indexSet(where predicate: @escaping (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> IndexSet {
        .init(try indices(where: predicate))
    }
    func indexSet(of element: Element) -> [Index] {
        .init(indices(of: element))
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let array = [10, 20, 30, 5, 15, 25, 50]
let indices = array.indices { $0.isMultiple(of: 3) }

for index in indices {
    print("element:", array[index], "at:", index)
}
```

---

This will print

> element: 30 at: 2
>
> element: 15 at: 4

---

```
let group = ["H","H","E","D","G","D","G","E","D","B","A","B","A","A","G","C","C","H","D","G","H","B","E","F","F","C","E","A","B","C","F","F"]
let indices = group.indices(of: "A")
print(indices)
```

This will print

> [10, 12, 13, 27]

Comment: Downvoter if there is something wrong with my post please leave a comment. Just downvoting a post without an explanation wont help OP, me, you and/or future readers of this post.

Comment: note that the accepted answer returns an offset which is not the same as index. Not all collections indices are zero based. So you are downvoting the wrong post. Try the accepted answer with an array slice and then let me know if it works.