# How to find all indices of the matching array elements in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, filter

First of all, I do not need the first index which is matching. I need all of them.

Example to be clear:

```
let a = [1,5,2,6,7,3,4]
let indices = a.operatorINeed { $0 > 4 } // [1,3,4]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerated` and `compactMap` in combination to achieve this:

```
let indices = a.enumerated().compactMap { $1 > 4 ? $0 : nil }
```

Comment: element offset it is not the same as the element index. Not all collections are zero based. It works for arrays but not for subsequences (ie ArraySlices)

Answer (score 1):

I inspired from this one. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/41256191/3950721]

I create an extension to pass a predicate as an argument filtering for all types.

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    func indexes(predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> [Int] {
        var result: [Int] = []
        for (index, element) in enumerated() {
            if predicate(element) {
                result.append(index)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: `Comparable` works but it is only needed if you would sort your collection which is not the case here. What you need is to constrain the elements to `Equatable`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203950/2303865

Comment: Hashable may be enough? @LeoDabus

Comment: Hashable inherits from Equatable.